# logging in spring boot on cloud foundry application platform

Tags: rest, spring-boot, logging, cloud-foundry

How can I centrally log my spring boot REST services which are running in different applications on the cloud foundry platform? For example I want to log how much a particular services is requested. The log should also be persistent even if I have to restart / reset my application. I don't only want to see the last log entries with cf logs --recent. Is there a best practise?

Answer (score 1):

Your applications should configure their logging to write to stdout and stderr. The Cloud Foundry logging subsystem will automatically pick up everything written to stdout and stderr and send it to the log aggregator. See the [Application Logging docs](http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/streaming-logs.html) for more info.

To persist the logs and make them available for viewing and analysis, they should be streamed to an external log capture system. Some Cloud Foundry docs contain some [general information about configuring log streaming](http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/services/log-management.html) and some [specific instructions](http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/services/log-management-thirdparty-svc.html) for some popular log capture systems.